# R officer: Is it possible to print slide as image (jpg, png or other formats)

Tags: r, officer

I have a set of files all with 1 slide created with a custom template created with [R officer package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/officer.pdf)

Would like to print these individual slides as jpg or png. Current workflow is to print individual pptx files using the inbuilt print function and converting to image outside of R. The process to convert to image using office "Save As" function or a script is cumbersome.

Is there a plan to add this feature?

Answer (score 3):

The package {doconv} can help you.

See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doconv/readme/README.html

Function `to_miniature` create an image with your slides. (you will need LibreOffice).

```
pptx_file <- system.file(package = "doconv", "doc-examples/example.pptx")
to_miniature(pptx_file, width = 1000)
```

[image]